# React Translate two different fields in different languages

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm using `import Translate from 'react-translate-component'` and the question is following.
How can I use two different languages translation on two different fields. For example

```
Original: Hello this text should be in English
<Translate content="OriginalText" component="label" /> (France)
<Translate content="OriginalText" component="label" /> (Germany)
```

To seperate the translations I have two dropdown fields, what seperates and saves the state of each dropdown. At the moment It translates both fields to same languages, but i would like them to be different. How should i approach this kind of problem, is it possible even?

Hope you all understood what I meant.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the `locale` prop?

```
<Translate locale="fr" content="OriginalText" component="label" />
<Translate locale="de" content="OriginalText" component="label" />
```

Couldn't find it in the documentation in an example like this, but I can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/martinandert/react-translate-component/blob/master/index.js)